# how install a non pakage?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, ace

I want to install this software

[dl.acestream.org/ubuntu/14/acestream_3.0.2_ubuntu_14.04_x86_64.tar.gz](http://dl.acestream.org/ubuntu/14/acestream_3.0.2_ubuntu_14.04_x86_64.tar.gz)

after I downloaded and extracting I have a folder with files, how should install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's no package in the current repository so the safest method is to use a somewhat older version. There's a detailed guide that describes how to add the relevant repository and how to install this software at: `http://acestreamguide.com/linux/`

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could look at the "folder with files" - If you see a file called something like `README`, `INSTALL` or, in general, anything with uppercase names, read them. These files should tell you how to configure, build/make, and install the software.